# I'm confused with this 'otherwise'

Tags: usage, adverbs

> In linguistics, an adjunct is an optional, or *structurally
>   dispensable*, part of a sentence, clause, or phrase that, if removed or
>   discarded, will not ***otherwise*** affect the remainder of the sentence.
>   Example: In the sentence *John helped Bill in Central Park*, the phrase
>   *in Central Park* is an adjunct. (Wikipedia | [Adjunct (grammar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)#cite_ref-auto_1-0))

Is it proper?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it means "in any way, shape, or form".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please tell me what makes you think that it's not proper? I think it's as proper as can be. You can understand this passage the following way:

> an adjunct is an optional part of a sentence that even removing or discarding it will not, **in any way**, affect the remainder of the sentence

In other words, removing an adjunct from a sentence has no effect on the rest of the sentence whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. I've found that the learner's OED says it also means 'differently,' and I guess this is the one, but the other usage that means something like 'if it's not the case' has too much influence on me. I'm just getting to see that it's always other-wise.

Comment: **He thinks otherwise.** - in this case, yes, the meaning is similar to *differently* or *in a different way*. I understand your confusion now. Just remember that it can also mean **in any way**.