# What does "it would not otherwise have had " meaning in the following context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "it would not otherwise have had to transfer" meaning in the following context?

Extract from Conceptual framework para 4.43

A present obligation exists as a result of past events only if:

(a) the entity has already obtained economic benefits or taken an action; and

(b) as a consequence, the entity will or may have to transfer an economic resource that it would not otherwise have had to transfer.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/160789/what-does-otherwise-mean-in-this-sentence?rq=1

Comment: Is that appropriate to rearrange the sentence in such way: The entity would not have had to transfer (the economic resources) if a present obligation does not exist as a result of past events

Comment: The entity may have to 'transfer an economic resource' (pay) if it has already obtained economic benefits (but will not if it has not).